# Как находить нужный объект по клику из массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, html, express

Я получаю массив с БД вот такого плана:
[image: arr]

Затем из этого массива на странице появляются карточки:
[image: card]

Я хочу сделать коризину путем того, что при нажатии на какую-то карточку, этот объект с именем, ценой и картинкой будет отправлен в бд в раздел Покупки и в Корзине уже таким же образом из массива вставлять товары по таким же примерно карточкам

Но мне не понятно, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на Карточку, в бд уходил именно этот объект? Тоесть нажал на карточку с "Пицца 189р" и в бд ушел именно этот объект

Comment: Ну так у вас у каждого объекта есть свой уникальный id. В чем проблема передвавать его в БД?

Answer (score 0):

Онклик по *элемент списка товаров_01* и функция после онклика в которой условие определяющее какой блок какому объекту соответствует.

Или просто онклик у каждого блока прям в хтмл и вызов функции которая ловит айди блока и сопоставляет айди товара с айди блока по которому кликнули.
Всё предельно просто.